# Practical examples/tutorials of using One-Class Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection, outlier, libsvm

I am a newbie in machine learning, and hope to solve an `anomaly detection` task  using `One-Class Support Vector Machines (OCSVM)`. Despite the availability of several general introductions, definitions and academic papers on OCSVM, I do not find tutorials with practical examples except a few provided by [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_outlier_detection_housing.html). I'd appreciate some pointers to such resources especially with code examples/datasets as this will aid better understanding, than reading academic papers.